# Glide 4 - ResourceDecoder on specific call

Tags: java, android, android-glide

After going through all Glide documentation and StackOverflow questions and answers, I cannot find any information regarding applying resource decoder for a single Glide call in version 4.

In version Glide 3, we can do this:

```
Glide.with(imagePreview.context)
          .load(mediaItem.path)
          .asBitmap()
          .decoder(decoderWithDownSampleAtMost(imagePreview.context))
          .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
          .skipMemoryCache(false)
          .dontAnimate()
          .into(target)
```

```
private fun decoderWithDownSampleAtMost(ctx: Context): GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder {
    return GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder(
        ImageVideoBitmapDecoder(StreamBitmapDecoder(Downsampler.AT_MOST,
            Glide.get(ctx).bitmapPool,
            DecodeFormat.DEFAULT),
            FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder(ctx)),
        GifResourceDecoder(ctx),
        Glide.get(ctx).bitmapPool)
  }
```

And in version 4, I know we can use `AppGlideModule` for custom `ResourceDecoder`

```
@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.prepend(String::class.java, Bitmap::class.java, GalleryDecoder(context))
    }
}
```

However, this applies to all Glide calls. How can I make `ResourceDecoder` behave like v3: the ability to apply on individual call?

---

**UPDATE:**
I'm able to draw out a solution for this one after consulting on `Glide Github Issues` here https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3522

So basically, I need to create a custom `Option` and use it to determine whether my custom `ResourceDecoder` will be triggered. Here is my sample:

- Normal `AppGlideModule`

```
@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.prepend(Any::class.java, Bitmap::class.java, MainActivity.GalleryDecoder(context, glide.bitmapPool))
    }
}
```

- In my `Activity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        val GALLERY_DECODER: Option<Boolean> = Option.memory("abc")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        GlideApp.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("link_or_path_here")
            .apply(option(GALLERY_DECODER, true))
            .into(image_view)

    }
}
```

- My `GalleryDecoder`:

```
open class GalleryDecoder(
        private val context: Context,
        private val bitmapPool: BitmapPool
    ) : ResourceDecoder<Any, Bitmap> {

        override fun decode(source: Any, width: Int, height: Int, options: Options): Resource<Bitmap>? {
            return BitmapResource.obtain(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.giphy), bitmapPool)
        }

        override fun handles(source: Any, options: Options): Boolean = options.get(GALLERY_DECODER) ?: false

    }
```

That's it, if you don't want to use `GalleryDecoder`, just remove `.apply(option(GALLERY_DECODER, true))` from Glide load. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do with :

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
        // TRY With below line....
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(new GlideOptions().decode(Class<T> class))
        .load(R.drawable.ic_loader)
        .into(imageView);
```

I think you have to pass your class object. I haven't tried but I think it will work.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work, `Class<T>` here means common resource type like `Drawable`, `Bitmap`, not `ResourceDecoder`

Comment: While reading `Glide` code, I notice that we can `registry.prepend` with custom `buckets` (identifier), but still looking for the way to do this