# With Glide, can I more directly get byte data?

Tags: android, android-glide

Glide 4.11+ only

With Glide, I can do this and **get a bitmap**, which is awesome,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent tent){
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
  .load(tent.getData())
  .apply(new RequestOptions().override(300, 400))
  .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap glideBitmap,
              @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

      Log.i("c", "BAM! Just like that, a bitmap ...");
```

Awesome.

However, often I need an actual bite array,

I do this ..

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent tent){
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
  .load(tent.getData())
  .apply(new RequestOptions().override(300, 400))
  .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap glideBitmap,
              @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

      // convert badly to a byte array...

      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      glideBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
      byte[] byteData = baos.toByteArray();

      Log.i("c", "had to work for bytes :/ ...");
```

I assume real droid programmers laugh at me?

Is there a **more direct way** to get a byte array from Glide?

---

Use case - am sending this up to Firebase in the usual byteish way,

```
  UploadTask uploadTask = storeRef.putBytes(byteData);
```

Maybe I am XY, can Glide actually return a *stream*?  As you know to send to Firebase you need either a stream or byte data.  If so, sorry for being a lame-ass ios dev.

Comment: In this article here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki scroll down to the section or search `Transcoding` where you'll see `toBytes` method. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: thahk you so much @MayurGajra - ah, but there's no way to tell Glide "jpeg, 70%" ?

Answer (score 1):

You ought to replace `asBitmap` with `as(byte[].class)`.

Comment: Thanks again - as I was asking Mayur, do you know if there's a way to  tell Glide "jpeg, 70%" ?  (or PNG etc?)

Comment: @Fattie I think you need custom `ResourceDecoder`. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54360199/2894324